# What is Jamboree on the Air (JOTA)?

Tags: jargon, jota

What does this term mean? I'm not good with radio terms at all, but I was especially curious about this one...

Answer (score 13):

The Jamboree-on-the-Air, or JOTA, is an annual Scouting event that uses amateur radio to link Scouts around the world. Held on the third full weekend of October each year since 1958, this worldwide jamboree requires no travel, other than to a nearby radio amateur’s ham shack.

Over 500,000 Scouts participate in JOTA, making it the largest single Scouting event and the largest amateur radio event.

Information from the World Organization of the Scouting Movement (WOSM) on JOTA:

http://www.scout.org/jota-joti-about

Information from the Boy Scouts of America (BSA) about JOTA:

http://www.scouting.org/JOTA.aspx

The BSA has a comprehensive list of the frequencies used for JOTA:

http://www.scouting.org/jota/operators_guides.aspx